# How to display data in every row and not have merged columns due to row grouping

Tags: reporting-services, format, row, grouping, rdlc

I would like to have data in every line of my report and not grouped.  I need the data grouped so counts can be summed but I wish to have data displayed in every line for further reporting activities. I'm a complete newbie at reports but can't seem to find a solution to what I would assume would be a straightforward report option.

I have tried to display my desires textually as I cannot post a picture as a new member.

A -- 1 -- Bike

A -- 1 -- Car

A -- 2 -- Car

Rather than

A -- 1 -- Bike

```
      Car

  2 -- Car
```

Any help would be much appreciated.